# Prevent mouse pointer events interfering with simulated events

Tags: javascript, dom, mouseevent, mouse, pointerlock

I am trying to simulate mouse events to perform an action in the DOM like making a selection by moving the pointer from point A to pointer B. Here is an example of the event that I am using.

```
const start = {
    clientX: start.left + 1,
    clientY: start.top + start.height / 2,
    bubbles: true,
    shiftKey: false,
};

const end = {
    clientX: end.right,
    clientY: end.bottom - end.height / 2,
    bubbles: true,
    shiftKey: false,
};

target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousedown', end));
target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mousemove', start));
target.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('mouseup', start));
```

This makes a selection on the `target` element. This works fine but if the user moves their mouse during this brief period, the user's cursor's mouse events interfere with the simulated events and the selection messes up.

I have tried using `element.requestPointerLock()` but this shows an info bubble on the screen until I release the pointer lock.

Is there a way to prevent user's pointer events from interfering with the simulated event (events dispatched from the code)?

Comment: Could you please elaborate and provide some code. It's not possible to move the user's cursor and it's pretty unclear what these 'simulated' events are.

Comment: I have updated the question with sample code snippet of the simulated events.